# Storyboard crash with error Xcode 7 / Swift 2 - Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, swift2, xcode7

When I click on the storyboard file in xcode, it will not load, then crashes. In the error tab, this appears:

Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try do clean your project (cmd + k) and close Xcode, and then go to your derivedData folder :

/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

and delete the folder of your application. Launch Xcode and the folder will be created again but maybe without this bug.

Hope this will work.

Comment: As much as I wanted it to work, it didn't. The error is still there and xcode still crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a project from Xcode 6.3, migrated with Xcode ?

Comment: Yes, now in xcode 7 beta 4. I just noticed that in my navigation bar, all my products are highlighted red (.app , tests, UITests). Does that mean anything?

Comment: Yes, try to fix these problems first

Comment: Ok, I fixed the red highlighting, but xcode still crashes